# Pop up dialog box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, jquery, razor

I am using ASP.net MVC3, coding in VB.net with razor aswell.

Is there any way that i can get like a small dialog box to pop up when the user performs certain actions? Similiar to a JQuery box - so that when a user creates an account they get a confirmation popup box appear and are then redirected or if they enter in the incorrect syntax they will view a error dialog box on button click describing their problem.

I have tried to integrate a package from `Nuget` to solve this but am having major issues when installing it.

So i was wondering whether the mcv EF or razor environment have any of this built in where i can simply type it in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I'v always used jquery's .dialog:http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

There isn't any built in one.